# Convert rows to column with one column data SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with rows like below

```
StoreId   | ToyId
-------------------
100       | Toy1
100       | Toy2
101       | Toy1
102       | Toy1
103       | Toy1
103       | Toy2
103       | Toy3
```

The number of ToyID per store is not limited to 3. A store can have one or many toy ids.
I want to get result as:

```
StoreId | ToyId1 | ToyId2 | ToyId3
-----------------------------------
100     | Toy1   | Toy2   | NULL   
101     | Toy1   | NULL   | NULL
102     | Toy1   | NULL   | NULL
103     | Toy1   | Toy2   | Toy3
```

How can i achieve in SQL?
It is not entire row to column pivoting, The rows dynamically get added based on number of unique rows of one column only.

Comment: This question has been answered numerous times here in SO. Please do some research before writing a new post.

Comment: I have gone through the original link and other links. First of all,  I do not want entire pivoting.All answers posted have fixed rows (3), my rows are dynamic. Hence I consider this as a new question

Comment: The answer by @bluefeet in the link of the duplicate answer also addresses the issue of dynamic *columns*. The number of rows is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Can you please test it once before commenting... It moves the entire table as row with one of the columns as column name. I do not want this. I want to make only one column to be converted to row based on a ID not the ENTIRE table

Comment: @Aruna Did find the anwer as you required

Comment: No. i am still searching

Comment: @Aruna i have answer but how i could i send you

Comment: According to  @GiorgosBetsos i tried with pivot but it will work only if column name is same as column data. But that is not my case. I have different data and column names are in no relation with the column data.